# Study of the sequence $\int_0^n \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n e^{-\alpha x}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lebesgue-integral

I wish to understand the following sequence:
$$b_n:=\int_0^n \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n e^{-\alpha x}\mathrm{d}x,$$
where $\alpha$ is a real number and the integral here is Lebesgue's (although I don't know if this will be useful).

I already proved that it is increasing (that is $b_{n+1}\geq b_n$) and that

- If $\alpha>1$, then $b_n\leq \frac{1}{\alpha -1}$. This implies the convergence of $b_n$ but I still don't know the limit.
- If $\alpha<-1$, I proved that $b_n$ diverges.

Obviously, if $\alpha=0$, then $(b_n)$ diverges. However, if $\alpha\in [-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$ I still don't know the behaviour of $(b_n)$ and, even when it converges, I don't know its limit.

Comment: The point of this exercise is to recognize how to use the dominated or monotone convergence theorem to justify that $b_n \to \int_0^{\infty} e^x \cdot e^{-\alpha x} \, dx$.

Comment: If $\alpha \le 0,$ this should be easy.

Comment: @T.Bongers I think the MCT will be the way to go, since in the cases remaining, there is no dominating $L^1$ function.

Comment: I thought this too. If $b_n$ was defined as the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ I could do it. However I don't know how to deal with the $n$ in the limits of the integral.

Comment: @zhw. I proved that $b_n\geq \frac{(-\alpha)^n n}{2n+1}$. So I had to utilize $\alpha<-1$ to prove the divergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the main difficulties here is that both the integrand and the interval are changing. We need to reduce the number of things going on.

So instead of thinking about the bounds of the integral changing, think of this as integrating against a characteristic function that changes. That is, write

$$b_n = \int_0^{\infty} \chi_{[0, n]}(x)\left(1 + \frac x n \right)^n e^{-\alpha x} \, dx$$

Now study the integrand as a function of $n$, and invoke monotone convergence.  You should find that

$$b_n \to \int_0^{\infty} e^x \cdot e^{-\alpha x} \, dx$$

which is finite if and only if $\alpha > 1$.

Comment: The simple idea of utilizing the characteristic function was incredible. That made the problem easy. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $f_n(x)=\chi_{[0,n]}(x)(1+x/n)^ne^{-\alpha x}.$ Then $0\le f_1\le f_2 \le \dots $ on $[0,\infty),$ and the pointwise limit of $f_n(x)$ there is $e^xe^{-\alpha x}.$